# Vagrant/Chef Windows Bootstrapping Issue

Tags: windows, vagrant, chef-infra

I'm fairly new to doing DevOps stuff in Windows so I think the issue here is a gap in my own knowledge that so far I've been unable to plug despite trawling the web for hours and hours.

I'm using Vagrant to spin up a VM then the Chef Client provisioner to actually provision that VM.

I've configured Vagrant to log in via WinRM using an Administrator account, which then installs and runs chef under that user.

One of the executables I'm installing with Chef installs it's own dependencies (Microsoft SQL Local Database) as the 'SYSTEM' user, and then the program as the Admin user. For some reason, the installation of the exe fails because it can't access the LocalDB server because it's installed as 'SYSTEM'.

In my Chef recipe there is a task to set up the chef client to run as a Windows scheduled task under the 'SYSTEM' user. Is there anyway to get Vagrant to provision the chef client, instruct it what role/recipes I want to use, but only run it under the 'system' user as a scheduled task?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Did you realise, there's now a SE beta site especially for DevOps? https://devops.stackexchange.com/  They're probably dying to answer your question :-)

Comment: What exactly is the error you get related to installation? Are you certain its an issue with access and not an issue with installation over `winrm`? There are some restrictions on stuff being installed over `winrm` and SQL happens to suffer from some of that.